# How to update dataframe based on some condition in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need one help to update pandas data frame based on some condition. I explain you scenario in the below example:

Ex:

df:

```
job_id    job_name    cat_value    sub_cat_value    dependency
100        case        prog_id       prod_nm   
200        ccaas       acct_id       case_id          300
300        eureka      intr_id       prod2            400
400        mdm         cmpnt_id      case_nmbr
500        ampil       src_id        status_nmbr
```

In above dataframe job_id 200 & 300 is dependent on 300 & 400 respectively. So based on the dependency I have to update the cat_value and sub_cat_value. I want final result in the respective manner-

```
job_id    job_name    cat_value    sub_cat_value    dependency   new_cat_value    new_sub_cat_value
100        case        prog_id       prod_nm   
200        ccaas       acct_id       case_id          300         cmpnt_id            case_nmbr
300        eureka      intr_id       prod2            400         cmpnt_id            case_nmbr 
400        mdm         cmpnt_id      case_nmbr
500        ampil       src_id        status_nmbr      100         prog_id             prod_nm
```

Comment: where did the row job_id 500 come from? Can't see it in the input df

Comment: @SreeramTP Sorry I missed that record.

Comment: Should `new_cat_value` in the `job_id=200` not be equal to `intr_id` instead of `cmpnt_id`?

Comment: @KenHBS Actually 200 is dependent on 300 but 300 again dependent on 400 . So in both the ids new_cat_value and new_sub_cat_value will be same.

Comment: @KenHBS It will always check on loop..